# ng-resource does not recognize parameters

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I'm using ng-resource to access an API in the following way:

```
$resource('http://' + config.server.api + config.server.host + base_url + '/:id', {
    'id': '@id'
    },{
    'get' : {
        method : 'GET'
    },
    'add' : {
        method : 'PUT'
    },
    'update' : {
        method : 'POST'
    },
    'all' : {
        method  : 'GET',
        isArray : true
    },
    'del' : {
        method : 'DELETE'
    }
},{
    stripTrailingSlashes : false
});
```

And I am accessing the resource like so:

```
apiService.Businesses.query(function(data){
  $scope.businesses = data;
});
```

---

However, the request URL is: [http://API_URL.com/businesses/:id](http://API_URL.com/businesses/%3aid)

Or when I try to use 'resource.get':

```
apiService.Businesses.get({id:1}, function(data){
  $scope.businesses = data;
});
```

The request URL is [http://API_URL.com/businesses/:id/[object%20Object]](http://API_URL.com/businesses/%3aid/%5bobject%20Object%5d)

---

I'm obviously missing something in the resource definition but I could not figure out what it was

Comment: Seems to **[work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/LHwuH/)**. There is something else wrong with your code. Something you are not showing us...

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what was the issue but switching the dependency seems to have solved it.

I'm using Bower and previously installed '**ng-resource**'.

I tried to uninstall it and use '**angular-resource**' instead and that did the trick.

Comment: ng-resource is not the official module.

Comment: Yeah I just installed from Bower assuming it is, angular-resource is from the official Angular repo.